# How to make types in the rows of pandas dataframe to become the column header with result as row type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df structured in following setting and would like to change it so that the types found in the column `type` are the the row readers with the original `result` as the row the new type column, condensing all `ids` into one row. For example, I would like to change the following table:

| id | name | type | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Apple | 1 | X |
| A | Apple | 2 | X |
| A | Apple | 3 | X |
| B | Banana | 1 | Y |
| B | Banana | 2 | Y |
| C | Cantaloupe | 2 | Z |
| C | Cantaloupe | 3 | Z |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

To:

| id | name | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Apple | X | X | X |
| B | Banana | Y | Y | None |
| C | Cantaloupe | None | Z | Z |
| ... | ... | ... |  |  |

Comment: Check out .pivot() in the docs

Comment: `df.pivot(['id','name'],'type','result')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pivot_table` with `rename_axis`:

```
>>> df.pivot_table('result', ['id', 'name'], 'type', aggfunc=''.join).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
  id        name    1  2    3
0  A       Apple    X  X    X
1  B      Banana    Y  Y  NaN
2  C  Cantaloupe  NaN  Z    Z
>>>
```