# How to make pivot table in pandas with row values as a column and separate rows based on date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df structured in following setting and would like to change it so that the types found in the column `measure` are the the row readers with the original `result` as the row the new type column, condensing `ids` of the same date into one row. For example, I would like to change the following table:

| id | name | measure | result | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | O1 | X | 2015 |
| 1 | A | O2 | X | 2015 |
| 1 | A | O3 | X | 2015 |
| 2 | B | O2 | Y | 2015 |
| 1 | A | O1 | Z | 2016 |
| 2 | B | O1 | Z | 2016 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

To:

| id | name | O1 | O2 | O3 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | X | X | 2015 |
| 2 | B | None | Y | None | 2015 |
| 1 | A | Z | None | None | 2016 |
| 2 | B | Z | None | None | 2016 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I know to use the `pivot_table` function in pandas; however, I am unsure how to take into account different years. Here are similar links to my question but don't answer the same question:
[How to make types in the rows of pandas dataframe to become the column header with result as row type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869465/how-to-make-types-in-the-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-to-become-the-column-header-wi)
[How to pivot a dataframe in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337117/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe-in-pandas)
[How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggfunc='first'` for string values. [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to cleanup format:

```
new_df = (
    df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'id', 'name'],
                   columns='measure',
                   values='result',
                   aggfunc='first')
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
)
# Re-order columns (move date to end)
new_df = new_df[[*new_df.columns[new_df.columns != 'date'], 'date']]
```

`new_df`:

```
   id name   O1   O2   O3  date
0   1    A    X    X    X  2015
1   2    B  NaN    Y  NaN  2015
2   1    A    Z  NaN  NaN  2016
3   2    B    Z  NaN  NaN  2016
```